# rm -f fails for missing files when using "bash -e" as shell in GNU Make 4

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make

I have a Makefile that looks as follows:

```
.ONESHELL:
SHELL = /bin/bash
.SHELLFLAGS = -e

clean:
    rm -f foo

.PHONY: clean
```

`foo` doesn't exist. When I run this on Debian, GNU Make 4.1 I get this error:

```
rm -f foo
/bin/bash: rm -f foo: No such file or directory
Makefile:6: recipe for target 'clean' failed
make: *** [clean] Error 1
```

When I run it on macOS, GNU Make 3.81 it works as expected. It makes no difference if I write `-rm -f` instead of `rm -f`.

Why do I get the error? Running `bash -e -c "rm -f foo" ; echo $?` in a shell prints `0` on both systems.

Am I missing something?

Comment: It's amazing that the [GNU manual page for .ONESHELL](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/One-Shell.html) does not mention this pitfall. It explicitly uses `.SHELLFLAGS = -e` in its examples, without considering that most users will *not* use `perl` as shell, but `bash` or something, and so mentioning `-ec` would save time for several people.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error message has to be read quite carefully:

```
/bin/bash: rm -f foo: No such file or directory
```

This isn't a message from `rm` saying it can't find `foo`, it's a message from Bash telling it can't find the file `rm -f foo` (with the spaces in the filename).

With `.SHELLFLAGS = -e`, the shell gets what would equal the command line:

```
bash -e "rm -f foo"
```

So it looks for a file `rm -f foo` to read commands from. You need to explicitly add the `-c` flag to tell it to take the argument itself as a command, i.e. `.SHELLFLAGS = -ec`, resulting in

```
bash -ec "rm -f foo"
```

Not surprisingly, the [default value](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html) for `.SHELLFLAGS` contains `-c`:

> The argument(s) passed to the shell are taken from the variable `.SHELLFLAGS`. The default value of `.SHELLFLAGS` is `-c` normally, or `-ec` in POSIX-conforming mode.

Comment: I thought it was *additional*  flags, but of course its isn't. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

That is an invalid setting for `.SHELLFLAGS`.  It will result in this being invoked:

```
/bin/sh -e 'rm -f foo'
```

which is not a valid command line; it's telling the shell to run a program named, literally, `rm -f foo` which is obviously wrong.  You have to be sure you add the `-c` option as well, and since many shells only allow options in the first argument, you'll need:

```
.SHELLFLAGS = -ec
```

This is documented in the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html#index-_002eSHELLFLAGS_002c-value-of).

The reason it "works" in the older GNU make 3.81 is that this version doesn't support the `.SHELLFLAGS` option at all, so that line is just ignored.